# Creating/re-naming added static files on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, static, operating-system, django-staticfiles

Hi I have an issue that is preventing some additional security on my website,
Bearing in mine, when run locally this all works perfectly.

Basically when it is being used my site will zip/ rename/ re-zip files (mostly image files)every three minuets after a certain request is made. But since deploying on heroku this does not work. it says it cant fine the file after zipping or re-naming it.

I am using Django 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a **read-only** filesystem. You can only write to `./tmp` and `./log` directories:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

> There are two directories that are writeable: ./tmp and ./log (under your application root). If you wish to drop a file temporarily for the duration of the request, you can write to a filename like #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/myfile_#{Process.pid}. There is no guarantee that this file will be there on subsequent requests (although it might be), so this should not be used for any kind of permanent storage.